# Are there any problems with the sentence, "make a big success to the art exhibitions"?

Tags: word-choice

Ok. According to the comments, it's a question testing set phrase. So I shouldn't be confused about which is the best meaning for it. No more questions like this kind.

Here is a question.
The University of Sydney makes a big __ to the art exhibitions by its excellent faculty and students.
A. success
B. impact 
C. contribution
D. use

The answer is C. I don't know why "success" isn't right. It is supposed to describe how well they held the art exhibitions.

Comment: It's a stupid test, because your choice is supposed to be made on the basis of *which **noun** works with the specific **preposition** here?* They're pointlessly confusing you by encouraging you to think about the (syntactically irrelevant) ***meanings*** of the four possible choices. And I'd be prepared to bet money that sentence wasn't even written by a competent native Anglophone in the first place (we native speakers would be much more likely to use ***through*** rather than ***by*** here).

Comment: And _the_ is almost certainly not appropriate. I have just replied to another question from the same OP and, apparently, the same test, where I pointed out two reasons why the question was not idiomatic English. #

Comment: And, rann rann, just as in my previous answer, you need to look at which words go with the options. _success **in**_ (or _with_); _impact **on**_; _contribution **to**_; _use **of**_; are the prepositions mainly used with these nouns

Comment: @ColinFine the word "the" is often used before the name of a University or other educational institution. We could have, "***The*** University of Wisconsin Madison". We can write "The University of California at Berkley", "The University of Oregon". These different Universities are all located in different geographic locations. The name of a University in the United States of America almost always begins with the word "The".

Comment: "[By](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by)" is definitely odd here - in this context it most naturally refers to agency (person/organisation doing something), but It's already said the university was the agent. Maybe it is meant to refer to the means/instrument ("They went by train", "He got rid of him by hitting him with a stick"), but this sounds odd with a human. "Thanks to" seems a better replacement, although "due to", "because of", or "through" would work.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon: That wasn't the "the" I was talking about. If the sentence is referring to some specific art exhibitions, "the" is fine, but that seems unlikely, given what the sentence says.

Comment: I'd expect "big success of the art exhibitions", at least if it held or organised them. But definitely not "to"

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is:

> The University of Sydney makes a big ***contribution*** to the art exhibitions by its excellent faculty and students.

The word "***contribution***" is similar in meaning to the word "***give***".

Long sentences can be difficult to understand. It might be easier if we re-write the long sentence as the concatenation of several simple short sentences.

There are art exhibitions. Art exhibitions are events at which people can look at paintings, photographs, sculptures. The University of Sydney has students. The University of Sydney has faculties. Faculties are instructors, professors, and teachers. The students paint paintings. The faculty (teachers) paint paintings. The paintings, sculptures, ceramic pots, etc are all examples of art. The word "art" has the same meaning as the string "decorative man-made objects". The students give their paintings, and other art, to the art exhibition. The faculty contribute artwork (paintings, teapots, plates, photographs) to the art exhibition. A large percentage of the art at the art exhibition was created by people associated with The University of Sydney.

Many of the paintings were ***contributed*** to the art show (art exposition) by students and teachers from the University.

The University of Sydney is a school. People learn at the University.